# Linking CMake target with OpenMP in a mixed C/C++ project with different compilers

Tags: c++, c, cmake, openmp

I have a library target `atc` which is fully written in C++ and therefore compiled with `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. `atc` provides a pure C interface which I want to test using the example executable `example-c`. However, `atc` uses OpenMP internally so I also need to link `example-c` using the correct flags. Right now I'm using this CMake code:

```
add_executable(example-c src/executables/example.c)
target_link_libraries(example-c atc)
if(OpenMP_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(example-c OpenMP::OpenMP_C)
endif()
[...]
```

As far as I know, using the target `OpenMP::OpenMP_<lang>` is the modern way of doing things, so I'm trying to use this. However, problems arise when `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is `clang` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` is `gcc` (default):

`cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fopenmp=libomp’; did you mean ‘-fopenmp-simd’?`

Checking the generated command, it turns out the Makefile is trying to **compile** (not link yet, although I had problems with this earlier too) `example-c` with `gcc` using the flags `-fopenmp=libomp -fopenmp`, with the first option not being a valid `gcc` option. This probably happens because some earlier targets are C++ targets and as such are compiled using `clang` and linked with the `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX` target.

Is there a way to make sure that when I link with a target of language `<lang>` with `OpenMP::OpenMP_<lang>`, CMake sets everything up specifically for `CMAKE_<lang>_COMPILER`, without interfering with the other targets in the project? For your information, I'm using CMake 3.10.2.

Comment: "However, problems arise when `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is `clang` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` is `gcc`" - yes, having in a **single CMake project** C and C++ compilers from **different "vendors"** is a direct way to problems. I am almost sure that OpenMP is not the only CMake module which fails to live in such settings. I would suggest to separate builds which use `gcc` from ones which use `clang`. (You could perfectly link libraries created in one build with libraries in another).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this limitation, thanks for the information. Since the C interface should be portable I thought it would be nice to test it out too, but I suppose that project would then have to be configured using a separate CMake project. In this case I'll probably just leave it like this since the user should use the same vendor twice anyway.

Comment: Well, I don't mean that it is an "official" limitation of CMake. At least, aside from using OpenMP, you have successfully configured the different compilers, haven't you? What I meant in my previous comment is that (some) CMake modules probably don't take this difference into account.

Comment: Well, honestly I haven't tested this set-up without OpenMP, so I'm not sure. It worked for both gcc and clang when I used the "same" C/C++ compiler, and there aren't many other special compiler/linker flags involved in my project AFAIK, so probably this is the only problem. But if CMake modules generally aren't supposed to handle this I don't see a point in trying to "fix" my set-up.